# How to use a loop in Vim to define multiple mappings

Tags: vim

In Vim is there a way to define multiple mappings with a loop?

For example this is how you would define it without a loop.

```
nnoremap<leader>1 1gt
nnoremap<leader>2 2gt
nnoremap<leader>3 3gt
```

But I'd like to do something like this with a loop.

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]
  nnoremap<leader>${i} ${i}gt
endfor
```

Is there a way to do some type of interpolation?

Comment: Nitpick: it's `<Leader>` ;)

Comment: @CongMa doesn't really matter both work.

Comment: @CongMa Is that the idiomatic way? I keep everything lower case so for example (<leader>, <esc>, <cr>).

Comment: @Petesta It probably doesn't matter much, hence "nitpick" ;) but it occurs to me the use of capital `L` in `<Leader>` is more or less by convention..

Comment: Just a quick comment: I've used a similar system in the past and found it to be slower than normal mappings.

Comment: @romainl How noticeable was the slowdown using the `range()` function for multiple definitions?

Comment: It is not really noticeable unless you look at the numbers but if you are going for a lean setup and a quick startup that's the kind of thing that can make the difference. It was two times slower, IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the `:execute` command:

```
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..   Executes the string that results from the evaluation
                        of {expr1} as an Ex command.
```

So your example would be

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]
  execute 'nnoremap <leader>'.i.' '.i.'gt'
endfor
```

Comment: The `range()` function is probably useful instead of manually creating the list. See `:help range()`

Comment: Ahh yes `range()` is definitely better. I was just using a loop as an example.